# Unable to install oracle package with npm

Tags: node.js, oracle, debugging, installation, npm

I followed the instalation guide and still doesn't work.

I haven't been able to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

node-gyt rebuild works fine when I do it.

Any enlightenment is welcome

OS: Win 7

Console:

```
C:\TRIVIA>npm install oracle
npm WARN package.json trivia@0.1.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json trivia@0.1.0 No README data

> oracle@0.3.6 install C:\TRIVIA\node_modules\oracle
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\TRIVIA\node_modules\oracle>node "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
) não era esperado nesta altura.
gyp: Call to 'IF DEFINED OCI_VERSION (echo %OCI_VERSION%) ELSE (echo 11)' returned exit status 1.
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:337:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:797:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\TRIVIA\node_modules\oracle
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.25
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! oracle@0.3.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the oracle@0.3.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the oracle package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls oracle
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "oracle"
npm ERR! cwd C:\TRIVIA
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.24
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\TRIVIA\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

npm-debug.log

````
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'oracle' ]
2 info using npm@1.3.24
3 info using node@v0.10.25
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\\node.exe
5 warn package.json trivia@0.1.0 No repository field.
6 warn package.json trivia@0.1.0 No README data
7 verbose readDependencies using package.json deps
8 verbose cache add [ 'oracle', null ]
9 verbose cache add name=undefined spec="oracle" args=["oracle",null]
10 verbose parsed url { protocol: null,
10 verbose parsed url   slashes: null,
10 verbose parsed url   auth: null,
10 verbose parsed url   host: null,
10 verbose parsed url   port: null,
10 verbose parsed url   hostname: null,
10 verbose parsed url   hash: null,
10 verbose parsed url   search: null,
10 verbose parsed url   query: null,
10 verbose parsed url   pathname: 'oracle',
10 verbose parsed url   path: 'oracle',
10 verbose parsed url   href: 'oracle' }
11 silly lockFile 431364b6-oracle oracle
12 verbose lock oracle C:\Users\Mezzarine\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\431364b6-oracle.lock
13 silly lockFile 431364b6-oracle oracle
14 silly lockFile 431364b6-oracle oracle
15 verbose addNamed [ 'oracle', '' ]
16 verbose addNamed [ null, '*' ]
17 silly lockFile a4fb3172-oracle oracle@
18 verbose lock oracle@ C:\Users\Mezzarine\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\a4fb3172-oracle.lock
19 silly addNameRange { name: 'oracle', range: '*', hasData: false }
20 verbose url raw oracle
21 verbose url resolving [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/', './oracle' ]
22 verbose url resolved https://registry.npmjs.org/oracle
23 info trying registry request attempt 1 at 01:31:30
24 verbose etag "326N682G60LOHGMDDUJYO7S2"
25 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/oracle
26 http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/oracle
27 silly registry.get cb [ 304,
27 silly registry.get   { date: 'Wed, 19 Feb 2014 01:31:27 GMT',
27 silly registry.get     server: 'Apache',
27 silly registry.get     connection: 'Keep-Alive',
27 silly registry.get     'keep-alive': 'timeout=10, max=50',
27 silly registry.get     etag: '"326N682G60LOHGMDDUJYO7S2"',
27 silly registry.get     'cache-control': 'max-age=1',
27 silly registry.get     vary: 'Accept' } ]
28 verbose etag oracle from cache
29 silly addNameRange number 2 { name: 'oracle', range: '*', hasData: true }
30 silly addNameRange versions [ 'oracle',
30 silly addNameRange   [ '0.1.0',
30 silly addNameRange     '0.1.1',
30 silly addNameRange     '0.1.2',
30 silly addNameRange     '0.1.3',
30 silly addNameRange     '0.2.0',
30 silly addNameRange     '0.3.0',
30 silly addNameRange     '0.3.1',
30 silly addNameRange     '0.3.2',
30 silly addNameRange     '0.3.3',
30 silly addNameRange     '0.3.4',
30 silly addNameRange     '0.3.5',
30 silly addNameRange     '0.3.6' ] ]
31 verbose addNamed [ 'oracle', '0.3.6' ]
32 verbose addNamed [ '0.3.6', '0.3.6' ]
33 silly lockFile 57fab89f-oracle-0-3-6 oracle@0.3.6
34 verbose lock oracle@0.3.6 C:\Users\Mezzarine\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\57fab89f-oracle-0-3-6.lock
35 silly lockFile 57fab89f-oracle-0-3-6 oracle@0.3.6
36 silly lockFile 57fab89f-oracle-0-3-6 oracle@0.3.6
37 silly lockFile a4fb3172-oracle oracle@
38 silly lockFile a4fb3172-oracle oracle@
39 silly resolved [ { name: 'oracle',
39 silly resolved     description: 'Oracle database driver',
39 silly resolved     keywords: [ 'database', 'db', 'oracle' ],
39 silly resolved     homepage: 'https://github.com/joeferner/node-oracle',
39 silly resolved     license: 'MIT',
39 silly resolved     version: '0.3.6',
39 silly resolved     engines: { node: '>=0.6.0' },
39 silly resolved     maintainers: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
39 silly resolved     bugs: { url: 'https://github.com/joeferner/node-oracle/issues' },
39 silly resolved     repository:
39 silly resolved      { type: 'git',
39 silly resolved        url: 'git://github.com/joeferner/node-oracle.git' },
39 silly resolved     dependencies: {},
39 silly resolved     devDependencies: { nodeunit: '~>0.8.0' },
39 silly resolved     scripts:
39 silly resolved      { test: 'nodeunit test/integration.js test/outparams.js',
39 silly resolved        install: 'node-gyp rebuild' },
39 silly resolved     main: './index.js',
39 silly resolved     gypfile: true,
39 silly resolved     readme: '# Oracle driver for Node.js\n\nA driver to connect to an Oracle database from node.js, leveraging the "Oracle C++ Call Interface" (OCCI)\nfor connectivity.  This is most commonly obtained as part of the Oracle Instant Client.\n\nIt is known to work with Oracle 10, 11, and 12, and has been mostly tested on Linux, but should also work on OS X and\nWindows 7+\n\n\n# Basic installation\n\n(See INSTALL.md for complete instructions for your platform.)\n\n* Prerequisites:\n  * Python 2.7 (*not* v3.x), used by node-gyp\n  * C++ Compiler toolchain (GCC, Visual Studio or similar)\n* Download the latest Oracle Instant Client Basic and SDK, and extract to the same directory.\n* Set environment variables:\n\n\t```\nOCI_LIB_DIR=/path/to/instant_client\nOCI_INCLUDE_DIR=/path/to/instant_client/sdk/include\nOCI_VERSION=<10, 11, or 12> # Integer. Optional, defaults to \'11\'\nNLS_LANG=.UTF8 # Optional, but required to support international characters\n\t```\n* Create symlinks for libclntsh and libocci in the Instant Client directory (see INSTALL.md)\n* (Linux) Install libaio\n* Configure the dynamic library path on your platform to include $OCI_LIB_DIR (see INSTALL.md)\n* `npm install oracle` to get the latest from npmjs.org\n\n\n# Examples\n\n### Basic example\n\n```javascript\nvar oracle = require(\'oracle\');\n\nvar connectData = {\n\thostname: "localhost",\n\tport: 1521,\n\tdatabase: "xe", // System ID (SID)\n\tuser: "oracle",\n\tpassword: "oracle"\n}\n\noracle.connect(connectData, function(err, connection) {\n\tif (err) { console.log("Error connecting to db:", err); return; }\n\n\tconnection.execute("SELECT systimestamp FROM dual", [], function(err, results) {\n\t\tif (err) { console.log("Error executing query:", err); return; }\n\n\t\tconsole.log(results);\n\t\tconnection.close(); // call only when query is finished executing\n\t});\n});\n```\n\n### Alternative connection using TNS\nReplace the `connectData` object above with one of the following.\n\nWithout tnsnames.ora file:\n\n```javascript\nvar connString = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=xe)))";\nvar connectData = { "tns": connString, "user": "test", "password": "test" };\n```\nWith tnsnames.ora file:\n\n```text\nDEV =\n\t(DESCRIPTION =\n\t\t(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))\n\t\t(CONNECT_DATA =\n\t\t\t(SERVER = DEDICATED)\n\t\t\t(SERVICE_NAME = orcl)\n\t\t)\n\t)\n```\n\n```javascript\nvar connectData = { "tns": "DEV", "user": "test", "password": "test" };\n```\n\n### Connection options\n\nThe following options can be set on the connection:\n\n* `connection.setAutoCommit(true/false);`\n* `connection.setPrefetchRowCount(count);` Should improve performance with large result sets\n\n### Out Params\nFollowing the basic example above, a query using a return parameter looks like this:\n\n```javascript\n\t...\n\tconnection.execute(\n\t\t"INSERT INTO person (name) VALUES (:1) RETURNING id INTO :2",\n\t\t[\'joe ferner\', new oracle.OutParam()],\n\t\tfunction(err, results) {\n\t\t\tif ( err ) { ... } \n\t\t\t// results.updateCount = 1\n\t\t\t// results.returnParam = the id of the person just inserted\n\t\t\tconnection.close();\n\t\t}\n\t);\n\t...\n```\n\nThe following OUT Params are supported in Stored Procedures:\n\n* `OCCIINT`\n* `OCCISTRING`\n* `OCCIDOUBLE`\n* `OCCIFLOAT`\n* `OCCICURSOR`\n* `OCCICLOB`\n* `OCCIDATE`\n* `OCCITIMESTAMP`\n* `OCCINUMBER`\n* `OCCIBLOB`\n\nSpecify the return type in the OutParam() constructor:\n\n```javascript\nconnection.execute("call myProc(:1,:2)", ["nodejs", new oracle.OutParam(oracle.OCCISTRING)], ...\n```\n\nWhen using `OCCISTRING`, the size can optionally be specified (default is 200 chars):\n\n```javascript\nconnection.execute("call myProc(:1,:2)", ["nodejs", new oracle.OutParam(oracle.OCCISTRING, {size: 1000})], ...\n```\nSee tests for more examples.\n\n### In/Out Params\nThe following INOUT param types are supported:\n\n* `OCCIINT`\n* `OCCISTRING`\n* `OCCIDOUBLE`\n* `OCCIFLOAT`\n* `OCCINUMBER`\n\nINOUT params are used like normal OUT params, with the optional \'in\' paramater value being passed in the options object:\n\n```javascript\nconnection.execute("call myProc(:1)", [new oracle.OutParam(oracle.OCCIINT, {in: 42})], ...\n```\n\n### Validate connection\nTo validate whether the connection is still established after some time:\n\n```javascript\nif (!connection.isConnected()) {\n\t// Do something like retire this connection from a pool\n}\n```\n\n### Dates\nFor DATE and TIMESTAMP types, the driver uses the UTC methods from the Javascript Date object. This means the DATE\nvalue stored will match the value of `new Date().toISOString()` on your client machine.  Consider this example\nfor a client machine in "GMT-0700":\n\nTable schema:\n\n```sql\nCREATE TABLE date_test (mydate DATE)\n```\n\nJavascript code:\n\n```javascript\n...\n\tvar date = new Date(2013, 11, 24, 18, 0, 1);  // Client timezone dependent\n\tconsole.log(date.toString());      // Tue Dec 24 2013 18:00:01 GMT-0700 (MST)\n\tconsole.log(date.toISOString());   // 2013-12-25T01:00:01.000Z\n\n\tconnection.execute(\n\t\t"INSERT INTO date_test (mydate) VALUES (:1) " +\n\t\t\t"RETURNING mydate, to_char(mydate, \'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS\') INTO :2, :3",\n\t\t[date, new oracle.OutParam(oracle.OCCIDATE), new oracle.OutParam(oracle.OCCISTRING)],\n\t\tfunction(err, results) {\n\t\t\tconsole.log(results.returnParam.toString());  // Tue Dec 24 2013 18:00:01 GMT-0700 (MST)\n\t\t\tconsole.log(results.returnParam1);            // 2013-12-25 01:00:01\n\t\t}\n\t);\n...\n```\n\n### Querying large tables\n\nTo query large tables you should use a _reader_:\n\n* `reader = connection.reader(sql, args)`: creates a reader\n* `reader.nextRow(callback)`: returns the next row through the callback\n* `reader.nextRows(count, callback)` returns the next `count` rows through the callback. `count` is optional and `nextRows` uses the prefetch row count when `count` is omitted.\n* `connection.setPrefetchRowCount(count)`: configures the prefetch row count for the connection. Prefetching can have a dramatic impact on performance but uses more memory. \n\nExample:\n\n```javascript\nconnection.setPrefetchRowCount(50);\nvar reader = connection.reader("SELECT * FROM auditlogs", []);\n\nfunction doRead(cb) {\n\treader.nextRow(function(err, row) {\n\t\tif (err) return cb(err);\n\t\tif (row) {\n\t\t\t// do something with row\n\t\t\tconsole.log("got " + JSON.stringify(row));\n\t\t\t// recurse to read next record\n\t\t\treturn doRead(cb)\n\t\t} else {\n\t\t\t// we are done\n\t\t\treturn cb();\n\t\t}\n\t})\n}\n\ndoRead(function(err) {\n\tif (err) throw err; // or log it\n\tconsole.log("all records processed");\n});\n```\n\n### Large inserts or updates\n\nTo insert or update a large number of records you should use _prepared statements_ rather than individual `execute` calls on the connection object:\n\n* `statement = connection.prepare(sql)`: creates a prepared statement.\n* `statement.execute(args, callback)`: executes the prepared statement with the values in `args`. You can call this repeatedly on the same `statement`.\n\nExample:\n\n```javascript\n\nfunction doInsert(stmt, records, cb) {\n\tif (records.length > 0) {\n\t\tstmt.execute([records.shift()], function(err, count) {\n\t\t\tif (err) return cb(err);\n\t\t\tif (count !== 1) return cb(new Error("bad count: " + count));\n\t\t\t// recurse with remaining records\n\t\t\tdoInsert(stmt, records, cb);\n\t\t});\n\t} else {\n\t\t// we are done\n\t\treturn cb();\n\t}\n}\n\nvar statement = connection.prepare("INSERT INTO users (id, firstName, lastName) VALUES (:1, :2, :3)");\ndoInsert(statement, users, function(err) {\n\tif (err) throw err; // or log it\n\tconsole.log("all records inserted");\t\n});\n```\n\n# Limitations/Caveats\n\n* Currently no native support for connection pooling (forthcoming; use generic-pool for now.)\n* Currently no support for column type "Timestamp With Timezone" (Issue #67)\n* While the Oracle TIMESTAMP type provides fractional seconds up to 9 digits (nanoseconds), this will be rounded\n  to the nearest millisecond when converted to a Javascript date (a _data loss_).\n\n# Development\n* Clone the source repo\n* Follow the installation instructions to prepare your environment (using Oracle Instant Client)\n* Run `npm install` or `npm test` in the root of the source directory\n* Point to an Oracle instance of your choice.  The free Oracle Express edition works well:\n  * Oracle Express 11g: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.htmlDownload\n* Debugging:\n  * Compile node with debug symbols\n  * Use gdb/ddd or another C++ debugger to step through\n',
39 silly resolved     readmeFilename: 'README.md',
39 silly resolved     _id: 'oracle@0.3.6',
39 silly resolved     _from: 'oracle@' } ]
40 info install oracle@0.3.6 into C:\TRIVIA
41 info installOne oracle@0.3.6
42 info C:\TRIVIA\node_modules\oracle unbuild
43 verbose tar unpack C:\Users\Mezzarine\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\oracle\0.3.6\package.tgz
44 silly lockFile 6c3b0595-tar-C-TRIVIA-node-modules-oracle tar://C:\TRIVIA\node_modules\oracle
45 verbose lock tar://C:\TRIVIA\node_modules\oracle C:\Users\Mezzarine\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\6c3b0595-tar-C-TRIVIA-node-modules-oracle.lock
46 silly lockFile 184b2831-m-cache-oracle-0-3-6-package-tgz tar://C:\Users\Mezzarine\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\oracle\0.3.6\package.tgz
47 verbose lock tar://C:\Users\Mezzarine\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\oracle\0.3.6\package.tgz C:\Users\Mezzarine\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\184b2831-m-cache-oracle-0-3-6-package-tgz.lock
48 silly gunzTarPerm modes [ '755', '644' ]
49 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry package.json
50 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'package.json', 438, 420 ]
51 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry .npmignore
52 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ '.npmignore', 438, 420 ]
53 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry README.md
54 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'README.md', 438, 420 ]
55 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry LICENSE
56 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'LICENSE', 438, 420 ]
57 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry index.js
58 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'index.js', 438, 420 ]
59 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry lib/oracle.js
60 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'lib/oracle.js', 438, 420 ]
61 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry binding.gyp
62 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'binding.gyp', 438, 420 ]
63 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry INSTALL.md
64 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'INSTALL.md', 438, 420 ]
65 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry src/outParam.h
66 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'src/outParam.h', 438, 420 ]
67 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry src/commitBaton.h
68 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'src/commitBaton.h', 438, 420 ]
69 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry src/connection.h
70 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'src/connection.h', 438, 420 ]
71 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry src/executeBaton.cpp
72 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'src/executeBaton.cpp', 438, 420 ]
73 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry src/executeBaton.h
74 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'src/executeBaton.h', 438, 420 ]
75 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry src/nodeOracleException.h
76 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'src/nodeOracleException.h', 438, 420 ]
77 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry src/oracle_bindings.cpp
78 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'src/oracle_bindings.cpp', 438, 420 ]
79 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry src/oracle_bindings.h
80 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'src/oracle_bindings.h', 438, 420 ]
81 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry src/outParam.cpp
82 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'src/outParam.cpp', 438, 420 ]
83 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry src/connection.cpp
84 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'src/connection.cpp', 438, 420 ]
85 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry src/reader.cpp
86 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'src/reader.cpp', 438, 420 ]
87 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry src/reader.h
88 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'src/reader.h', 438, 420 ]
89 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry src/readerBaton.h
90 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'src/readerBaton.h', 438, 420 ]
91 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry src/rollbackBaton.h
92 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'src/rollbackBaton.h', 438, 420 ]
93 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry src/statement.cpp
94 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'src/statement.cpp', 438, 420 ]
95 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry src/statement.h
96 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'src/statement.h', 438, 420 ]
97 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry src/statementBaton.h
98 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'src/statementBaton.h', 438, 420 ]
99 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry src/utils.h
100 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'src/utils.h', 438, 420 ]
101 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry test/integration.js
102 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'test/integration.js', 438, 420 ]
103 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry test/outparams.js
104 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'test/outparams.js', 438, 420 ]
105 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry test/prepare.js
106 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'test/prepare.js', 438, 420 ]
107 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry test/reader.js
108 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'test/reader.js', 438, 420 ]
109 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry tests-settings.json
110 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'tests-settings.json', 438, 420 ]
111 silly lockFile 6c3b0595-tar-C-TRIVIA-node-modules-oracle tar://C:\TRIVIA\node_modules\oracle
112 silly lockFile 6c3b0595-tar-C-TRIVIA-node-modules-oracle tar://C:\TRIVIA\node_modules\oracle
113 silly lockFile 184b2831-m-cache-oracle-0-3-6-package-tgz tar://C:\Users\Mezzarine\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\oracle\0.3.6\package.tgz
114 silly lockFile 184b2831-m-cache-oracle-0-3-6-package-tgz tar://C:\Users\Mezzarine\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\oracle\0.3.6\package.tgz
115 info preinstall oracle@0.3.6
116 verbose readDependencies using package.json deps
117 verbose readDependencies using package.json deps
118 silly resolved []
119 verbose about to build C:\TRIVIA\node_modules\oracle
120 info build C:\TRIVIA\node_modules\oracle
121 verbose linkStuff [ false, false, false, 'C:\\TRIVIA\\node_modules' ]
122 info linkStuff oracle@0.3.6
123 verbose linkBins oracle@0.3.6
124 verbose linkMans oracle@0.3.6
125 verbose rebuildBundles oracle@0.3.6
126 info install oracle@0.3.6
127 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
128 info oracle@0.3.6 Failed to exec install script
129 info C:\TRIVIA\node_modules\oracle unbuild
130 info preuninstall oracle@0.3.6
131 info uninstall oracle@0.3.6
132 verbose true,C:\TRIVIA\node_modules,C:\TRIVIA\node_modules unbuild oracle@0.3.6
133 info postuninstall oracle@0.3.6
134 error oracle@0.3.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
134 error Exit status 1
135 error Failed at the oracle@0.3.6 install script.
135 error This is most likely a problem with the oracle package,
135 error not with npm itself.
135 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
135 error     node-gyp rebuild
135 error You can get their info via:
135 error     npm owner ls oracle
135 error There is likely additional logging output above.
136 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
137 error command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "oracle"
138 error cwd C:\TRIVIA
139 error node -v v0.10.25
140 error npm -v 1.3.24
141 error code ELIFECYCLE
142 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
````

Comment: possible duplicate of [installing node-oracle on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 Santiago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429551/installing-node-oracle-on-red-hat-enterprise-linux-server-release-6-4-santiago)

Comment: It's not the same thing, and I had the variables well set.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process to see why this:

```
npm-cli.js install oracle
```

causes this warning:

```
No repository field
```

- Open `package.json`
- Look for the `oracle` key
- Check the value, which indicates the version
- Go to the registry: https://registry.npmjs.org/oracle/
- See if the version indicated is there
- If not, check the latest: https://registry.npmjs.org/oracle/latest
- Copy the latest version number to `package.json`
- Retry `npm install oracle`

Remember:

> The most important things in your package.json are the name and version fields. Those are actually required, and your package won't install without them. The name and version together form an identifier that is assumed to be completely unique. Changes to the package should come along with changes to the version.

**References**

- [Specifics of npm's package.json handling](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json)
- [node package manager](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/npm)
- [semver: The semantic version parser used by npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semver)
- [Peer Dependencies](http://blog.nodejs.org/2013/02/07/peer-dependencies/)

Comment: Well, this was almost a year ago, I can't check now if it works or not since I dropped the project. But thanks anyway :)